# Query Slowness Despite Index

Tags: sql-server

### Problem

I need to create a chart of User Retention over time, similar to this:
[image: User Retention Image]

Ignoring the percenages for a minute, I have a query that shows unique users for a given "cohort" and then the number of users that come back. However, with the volume of data we've acquired over the last few weeks, the query no longer finishes.

### Query

```
;WITH dates AS
(
-- Set up the date range
SELECT convert(date,GETDATE()) as dt, 1 as Id
UNION ALL
SELECT DATEADD(dd,-1,dt),dates.Id - 1
FROM dates
WHERE Id >= -84
)
, cohort as (
-- create the cohorts
SELECT dt AS StartDate, 
    convert(date,CASE WHEN DATEADD(DD, 6, dt) > convert(date,GETDATE()) THEN convert(date,GETDATE()) ELSE DATEADD(DD, 6, dt) END) as EndDate, 
    CONCAT(FORMAT(dt, 'MMM dd'), ' - ', FORMAT(CASE WHEN DATEADD(DD, 6, dt) > GETDATE() THEN GETDATE() ELSE DATEADD(DD, 6, dt) END, 'MMM dd')) as Cohort,
    row_number() over (order by dt) as CohortNo
FROM dates A
WHERE  DATEPART(dw,dt)=1
)
 , cohortevent as (
-- The complete set of cohorts and their events
select c.*, e.*
from cohort c
left join Event e on e.eventtime between c.StartDate and C.EndDate
)
, Retained as(
-- Recursive CTE that works out how long each user has been retained
select c.StartDate,c.EndDate,c.CoHort,c.CohortNo,c.EventId,c.EventTime,c.Count,c.UserID, case when Userid is not null then 1 else 0 end as ret
from cohortevent c
union all
select c.StartDate,c.EndDate,c.CoHort,c.CohortNo,c.EventId,c.EventTime,c.Count,c.UserID, ret+1
from cohortevent c
join Retained on Retained.userid=c.userid and Retained.CohortNo=c.CohortNo-1 and Retained.eventid<c.eventid
)
, WeeksRetained as (
-- Get the highest number of weeks, which is the actual number per user (could probably be combined with previous CTE)
select StartDate, Enddate, Cohort, userID, 
    case when max(ret)=1 then '<1W' else '+'+convert(varchar,max(ret)-1)+'W' end as Weeks
from Retained
group by StartDate, Enddate, Cohort,userid
)
-- Finally pivot this by the number of weeks
select *
from 
(
select StartDate, EndDate, Cohort, Weeks, count(distinct userID) as UserCount
from WeeksRetained
group by StartDate, EndDate, Cohort, Weeks
) src
pivot
(
sum(UserCount)
for Weeks in ([<1W], [+1W], [+2W], [+3W], [+4W], [+5W], [+6W], [+7W], [+8W], [+9W], [+10W], [+11W], [+12W])
) piv
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

### Environment

All of the tables are CTE's except for "Event" which has two main columns we care about, UserId and EventTime.

### What I've tried

I've added indexes on both UserId and EventTime. I noticed the DTUs (this is an Azure SQL instance) were maxing out originally, but I've vertically scaled the database instance so the DB runs at 70% DTU usage and it's still not completing in 30+ minutes. There are currently only 40k rows in `Event`.

### Execution Plan Link

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HkB6xClKH

Comment: Upload the execution plan [here](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) and add the link to your question. Consider a calendar table or generate the date series in a CTE using `CROSS JOIN` rather than recursion. Here is [an example](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/144700/how-to-generate-list-of-dates-ie-every-day-for-the-past-2-years). I'm not suggesting that alone will address the performance problem.

Comment: Thanks, I added a link to the exectuion plan. The generation of the dates and cohort tables is fairly quick when I've broken those out separately, so I don't think those are the culprit.

Comment: How do I know if at all `Recursive CTE` is require ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Testing

Based on [your estimated execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HkB6xClKH) I tried to get some sample data and get an actual execution of your query. Remember that while I am trying to get closer to your issue, YMMV.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.[Event](EventId INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
                    EventTime date,
                    userid INT,
                    Count INT);
CREATE INDEX IX_EventTime_UserID
ON dbo.[Event](EventTime,userid);
CREATE INDEX IX_Event_UserId
ON dbo.[Event](userid)
INCLUDE(EventTIme,Count)

INSERT INTO dbo.[Event](EventTime,userid,Count)
SELECT TOP(100000) 
DATEADD(Minute,- ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)),GETDATE()),
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) % 2000,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
FROM MASTER..spt_values spt1
CROSS APPLY MASTER..spt_values spt2
```

[This](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SkdyinWtH) is the actual plan that came out.

While not all operators & plan choices are the same, some parts look like they could match. One of these are the high amount of spools & filters with high row counts:

[image]

The querytimestats here show as `60` seconds

```
 <QueryTimeStats CpuTime="58806" ElapsedTime="58867" />
```

> The generation of the dates and cohort tables is fairly quick when
>   I've broken those out separately, so I don't think those are the
>   culprit.

The performance can differ between separate executions and joining , filtering, ... on the execution of these date tables. It is much easier to calculate estimates on one small part than on everything at once.

Now, If I simply create a temporary table, and insert the results of the `cohortevent` cte into this temporary table to split up the work:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp(
StartDate date,EndDate date,CoHort varchar(50)
,CohortNo int,EventId int,EventTime date
,Count int,UserID int);
```

&

```
INSERT INTO #temp
SELECT c.StartDate,c.EndDate,c.CoHort,c.CohortNo,c.EventId,c.EventTime,c.Count,c.UserID
FROM cohortevent c;
```

The result is a query plan with less spools & better estimates due to not evaluating everything at once. 
You are kind of giving the optimizer a breather by splitting the query in two parts.

[Actual Execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HynCT3WFH)
With the query time stats:

```
 <QueryTimeStats CpuTime="4957" ElapsedTime="4961" />
&
 <QueryTimeStats CpuTime="2347" ElapsedTime="2348" />
```

~ 6 - 7 seconds

Adding one more temp table on the `cohort` cte gives me the execution time I would desire.

[Actual execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ryVmb6ZFr)
With querytimestats=

```
<QueryTimeStats CpuTime="2" ElapsedTime="2" />
```

&

```
<QueryTimeStats CpuTime="929" ElapsedTime="475" />
```

&

```
    <QueryTimeStats CpuTime="2304" ElapsedTime="2305" />
```

~3 seconds

With the resulting query:

```
CREATE TABLE #cohortevent(
StartDate date,EndDate date,CoHort varchar(50)
,CohortNo int,EventId int,EventTime date
,Count int,UserID int);

CREATE TABLE #cohort(
StartDate date,EndDate date,CoHort varchar(50)
,CohortNo int);


;WITH dates AS
(
    -- Set up the date range
    SELECT convert(date,GETDATE()) as dt, 1 as Id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(dd,-1,dt),dates.Id - 1
    FROM dates
    WHERE Id >= -84
)
, cohort as (
    -- create the cohorts
    SELECT dt AS StartDate, 
        convert(date,CASE WHEN DATEADD(DD, 6, dt) > convert(date,GETDATE()) THEN convert(date,GETDATE()) ELSE DATEADD(DD, 6, dt) END) as EndDate, 
        CONCAT(FORMAT(dt, 'MMM dd'), ' - ', FORMAT(CASE WHEN DATEADD(DD, 6, dt) > GETDATE() THEN GETDATE() ELSE DATEADD(DD, 6, dt) END, 'MMM dd')) as Cohort,
        row_number() over (order by dt) as CohortNo
    FROM dates A
    WHERE  DATEPART(dw,dt)=1
)
INSERT INTO #cohort(StartDate,EndDate,CoHort,CohortNo)
SELECT StartDate,EndDate,Cohort,CohortNo
FROM cohort;

;WITH cohortevent as (
    -- The complete set of cohorts and their events
    select c.*, e.*
    from #cohort c
    left join Event e on e.eventtime between c.StartDate and C.EndDate
)
INSERT INTO #cohortevent
(StartDate ,EndDate ,CoHort 
,CohortNo ,EventId ,EventTime 
,Count ,UserID )
SELECT c.StartDate,c.EndDate,c.CoHort,c.CohortNo,c.EventId,c.EventTime,c.Count,c.UserID
FROM cohortevent c;

;WITH Retained as(
    -- Recursive CTE that works out how long each user has been retained
    select c.StartDate,c.EndDate,c.CoHort,c.CohortNo,c.EventId,c.EventTime,c.Count,c.UserID, case when Userid is not null then 1 else 0 end as ret
    from #cohortevent c
    union all
    select c.StartDate,c.EndDate,c.CoHort,c.CohortNo,c.EventId,c.EventTime,c.Count,c.UserID, ret+1
    from #cohortevent c
    join Retained on Retained.userid=c.userid and Retained.CohortNo=c.CohortNo-1 and Retained.eventid<c.eventid
)
, WeeksRetained as (
    -- Get the highest number of weeks, which is the actual number per user (could probably be combined with previous CTE)
    select StartDate, Enddate, Cohort, userID, 
        case when max(ret)=1 then '<1W' else '+'+convert(varchar,max(ret)-1)+'W' end as Weeks
    from Retained
    group by StartDate, Enddate, Cohort,userid
)
-- Finally pivot this by the number of weeks
select *
from 
(
  select StartDate, EndDate, Cohort, Weeks, count(distinct userID) as UserCount
  from WeeksRetained
  group by StartDate, EndDate, Cohort, Weeks
) src
pivot
(
  sum(UserCount)
  for Weeks in ([<1W], [+1W], [+2W], [+3W], [+4W], [+5W], [+6W], [+7W], [+8W], [+9W], [+10W], [+11W], [+12W])
) piv
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)

DROP TABLE #cohortevent
DROP TABLE #cohort
```

This will not be the best performing version of your query but this should resolve the issue with your spools going crazy. You should also investigate other workarounds like using a calendar table like [@DanGuzman](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/44434/dan-guzman) mentioned.

Comment: Thank you for the work you put into this, this is by far the best researched answer I've ever received. I tried running the final query and I'm getting an interesting error `Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 33 Operand type clash: uniqueidentifier is incompatible with int`. Any thoughts?

Comment: @NickHeidke No problem, happy to help! I think one of the temporary tables was declared wrongly,  Probably the `#cohortevent ` table, are there uniqueidentifiers in the event table? Like probably `EventId ` ,  `UserId  `or  `Count `?

Comment: You're absolutely correct, I just had to modify the declaration of `#cohortevent` to change two of the `int` columns to `nvarchar` to support my source table. Quick fix!