# Query to get dates NOT in table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am building a booking app and part of this involves reserving a courtesy car.

Courtesy cars can be booked out for a period, e.g.

2nd April - 11 April
12 April - 19 April
etc...

These dates are stored in a courtesycarbooking table.

What I want to write is a query which can query the courtesycar and courtesycarbooking tables (they are related) for free dates. Free dates are those which are NOT in the booking table.

The user will specify, in a javascript widget, a start and end date for the courtesy car, which will be sent to the sql server.

How could/should a query like this be written?

Comment: Learn something.  Try something.  If you can't even attempt to create the query, how can you create the app???

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Answer (score 1):

To do what you want first step is generate a list of Dates  then join that reservation table to the generate list of dates.

Here is a [thread](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/144700/how-to-generate-list-of-dates-ie-every-day-for-the-past-2-years) on how to Generate list of Dates in MSSQL

From this result set select where List of dates table failed to joined to the reservation table.  The reservation columns will be filled with NULLs

To write a sample  query for you, have to know the structure the table and unique keys used to identify the records.